# Run PowerShell custom function in new window

Tags: powershell

```
Function Check-PC
{
$PC = Read-Host "PC Name"
If($PC -eq "exit"){EXIT}
Else{
Write-Host "Pinging $PC to confirm status..."
PING -n 1 $PC
}
```

This is a snippet of a function I have written into a PowerShell script.  I would like the function to run in a new instance of PowerShell, not in the main window.

Is it possible to run this in a separate process of PowerShell without writing it as a separate script and calling the script? Something like this:

```
$x= Start-Process powershell | Check-PC
```

I need to keep everything in one script if possible.

Comment: `start-process powershell -argumentlist "\`$PC = read-host 'pc name'; write-host 'Checking'; test-connection \`$PC"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell launch script in new instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23237473/powershell-launch-script-in-new-instance)

Answer (score 12):

Note: It is the involvement of `Start-Process` that complicates the solution significantly - see below. I**f `powershell` were invoked *directly* from PowerShell, you could safely pass a script block** as follows:

```sh
powershell ${function:Check-PC}  # !! Does NOT work with Start-Process
```

`${function:Check-PC}` is an instance of [variable namespace notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375): it returns the function's *body* as a *script block* (`[scriptblock]` instance); it is the more concise and faster equivalent of 
`Get-Content Function:Check-PC`.

If you needed to pass (positional-only) arguments to the script block, you'd have to append `-Args`, followed by the arguments as an *array* (`,`-separated).

---

#### `Start-Process` solution with an auxiliary self-deleting temporary file:

See the bottom half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45001523/45375) to a related question.

---

#### `Start-Process` solution with `-EncodedCommand` and Base64 encoding:

```sh
Start-Process powershell -args '-noprofile', '-noexit', '-EncodedCommand',
  ([Convert]::ToBase64String(
     [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes(
       (Get-Command -Type Function Check-PC).Definition
     )
  ))
```

The new `powershell` instance will not see your current session's definitions (unless they're defined in your profiles), so **you must pass the *body of your function* to it** (the source code to execute).

**`(Get-Command -Type Function Check-PC).Definition`** returns the *body* of your function definition as a *string*.

The string needs *escaping*, however, in order to be passed to the new Powershell process *unmodified*.
`"` instances embedded in the string are stripped, unless they are either represented as `\"` or tripled (`"""`).
(`\"` rather than the usual `` `" `` is needed to escape double quotes in this case, because PowerShell expects `\"` when passing a command to the `powershell.exe` executable.)

Similarly, if the string as a whole or a double-quoted string inside the function body ends in (a non-empty run of) `\`, that `\` would be interpreted as an *escape* character, so the `\` must be *doubled*.<sup>Thanks, [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral).</sup>

The most robust way to ***bypass* these quoting (escaping) headaches is to use a Base64-encoded string in combination with the `-EncodedCommand` parameter**:

- `[Convert]::ToBase64String()` creates a Base64-encoded string from a `[byte[]]` array.
- `[Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes()` converts the (internally UTF-16 -
  "`Unicode`") string to a `[byte[]]` array.

Note: **To also pass *arguments***, you have two options:

- You can "bake" them into the `-EncodedCommand` argument, *assuming you can call a command to pass them to* there - see below, which shows how to define your function as such in the new session, so you can call it by name with arguments.<sup>Thanks, [Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala)</sup>

  - The advantage of this approach is that you can pass *named* arguments this way. The disadvantage is that you are limited to arguments that have *string-literal* representations.
- You can use the (currently undocumented) **`-EncodedArguments` parameter**, to which you must similarly pass a Base64-encoded string, albeit based on the *CLIXML* representation of the array of arguments to pass

  - The advantage of this approach is that you can pass a wider array of data types, within the limits of the type fidelity that CLIXML serialization can provide - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375); the disadvantage is that only *positional* arguments are supported this way (although you could work around that by passing a *hashtable* that the target code then uses for *splatting* with the ultimate target command).
  - Here's a simplified, self-contained example, which uses `Write-Output` to echo the (invariably *positional*) arguments received:

```sh
$command = 'Write-Output $args'
$argList = 'foo', 42

Start-Process powershell -args '-noprofile', '-noexit', 
  '-EncodedCommand',
    ([Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command))),
  '-EncodedArguments',
    ([Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes(
      [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize($argList)
    )))
```

---

**In case you want to pass the *complete* function, so it can be called *by name* in order to pass *arguments* as part of the command string**, a little more work is needed.

```sh
# Simply wrapping the body in `function <name> { ... }` is enough.
$func = (Get-Command -Type Function Check-PC)
$wholeFuncDef = 'Function ' + $func.Name + " {`n" + $func.Definition + "`n}"

Start-Process powershell -args '-noprofile', '-noexit', '-EncodedCommand', `
  ([Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes("$wholeFuncDef; Check-PC")))
```

As stated above, you can "bake" any arguments to pass to your function - assuming they can be represented as *string literals* - into the `-EncodedCommand` argument, simply by appending them inside the `"$wholeFuncDef; Check-PC"` string above; e.g.,
`"$wholeFuncDef; Check-PC -Foo Bar -Baz Quux"`

---

#### `Start-Process` solution with regex-based escaping of the source code to pass:

[PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) suggests the following alternative, which uses a regex to perform the escaping.
The solution is more concise, but somewhat mind-bending:

```sh
Start-Process powershell -args '-noprofile', '-noexit', '-Command', `
  ('"' + 
   ((Get-Command -Type Function Check-PC).Definition -replace '"|\\(?=\\*("|$))', '\$&') +
   '"')
```

- `"|\\(?=\\*("|$))` matches every `"` instance and every nonempty run of `\` chars. - character by character - that directly precedes a `"` char. or the very end of the string.

  - `\\` is needed in the context of a regex to escape a single, literal `\`.
  - `(?=\\*("|$))` is a positive look-ahead assertion that matches `\` only if followed by `"` or the end of the string (`$`), either directly, or with further `\` instances in between (`\\*`).  Note that since assertions do not contribute to the match, the `\` chars., if there are multiple ones, are still matched one by one.
- `\$&` replaces each matched character with a `\` followed by the character itself (`$&`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) for the constructs you can use in the replacement string of a `-replace` expression.
- Enclosing the result in `"..."` (`'"' + ... + '"'`) is needed to prevent whitespace normalization; without it, any run of more than one space char. and/or tab char. would be normalized to a single space, because the entire string wouldn't be recognized as a *single* argument.

  - Note that if you were to invoke `powershell` *directly*, PowerShell would generally *automatically* enclose the string in `"..."` behind the scenes, because it does so for arguments that contain whitespace when calling an *external utility* (a native command-line application), which is what `powershell.exe` is - unlike the `Start-Process` *cmdlet*.
  - PetSerAl points out that the automatic double-quoting mechanism is not quite that simple, however (the specific content of the string matters with respect to whether automatic double-quoting is applied), and that the specific behavior changed in v5, and again (slightly) in v6.

Comment: with this logic, would I be able to pass arguments from the session the new powershell instance was launched from?

Comment: Was able to pass it modifying just the following: `...GetBytes("$wholeFuncDef; Check-PC -Parameter1 One -Parameter2 Two"))`. Thank ya!

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, good point: You can bake the arguments into the `-EncodedCommand` argument, but that limits you to arguments that have _string-literal_ representations - though it does have the advantage of supporting _named_ arguments. The `-EncodedArguments` approach allows you to pass a wider range of data types, though CLIXML serialization too has its limits with respect to type fidelity - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375).

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, I now realize that the "baked in" solution is what I should have spelled out to begin with, as the simplest way to include arguments. I've updated the answer to clarify, along with contrasting the two approaches to argument-passing.

Comment: Very informative, thank you for always sharing the knowledge.