# Powershell waits on cmd.exe differently depending on environment

Tags: powershell

Consider the powershell command:

```
cmd.exe "/c start notepad.exe"
```

Using powershell.exe (console) this command completes immediately after starting the cmd/notepad process and does not wait for notepad/cmd to exit. If I want it to wait for completion I have to pipe the output to Out-Null.

Using the powershell ISE this command blocks execution until notepad/cmd is closed.

Further, if I use create a new process (of powershell.exe) in a script running in powershell.exe using System.Diagnostics.Process and redirect standard output the script now blocks execution until notepad/cmd is closed. If I don't redirect output it does not block execution.

But if I use c# to create a new process with the same settings/start info, and run the same script with redirected output it doesn't block execution.

I'm at a loss here. Obviously it has something to do with the setup of the execution and output and maybe "cmd.exe". I'm hoping someone understands what's fundamentally happening behind the scenes differently in these cases. I know the ISE and cmd.exe isn't fully supported but the I don't know why the other 3 aren't consistent.

Why do the scripts not run with the same behavior (especially the powershell console ones) and how do I get them to?

---

Edit:

After some troubleshooting I was able to get all the powershell.exe versions to run the same (the ISE isn't of importance to me). The odd ball where `cmd.exe "/c start notepad.exe"` blocks execution is when a new process is created in powershell to run powershell.exe using `System.Diagnostics.Process`. If output is redirected (the reason I was using `System.Diagnostics.Process` in the first place, `Start-Process` doesn't support redirecting except to a file) then calling `WaitForExit()` on the process object causes the blocking to occur.

Simply substituting `WaitForExit()` with `Wait-Process` (and the process ID) causes the powershell script running in the new powershell.exe to execute as expected and exit after running the command. Hopefully this information combined with @mklement0 answer will be sufficient for anyone else having similar problems.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Why do the scripts not run with the same behavior (especially the powershell console ones) and how do I get them to?

Comment: Why though? What if it is what it is and you can't change the behaviors?

Comment: `start-process -wait -passthrough`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- `cmd.exe "/c start notepad.exe"` (conceptually clearer: `cmd.exe /c 'start notepad.exe'`) *should* result in *asynchronous* execution, given that `cmd.exe`'s internal `start` command launches applications asynchronously by default.

  - The fact that it *doesn't* in the Windows PowerShell *ISE* - unlike in any other environment - should be considered an *anomaly*, but at this time this is somewhat of a moot point, given the [obsolescent](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) status of the ISE.
- By contrast, `cmd.exe "/c notepad.exe"` (conceptually clearer: `cmd.exe /c notepad.exe`) *should and does* result in *synchronous* (blocking) execution, even in the PowerShell ISE, because `cmd.exe /c` as well as *batch files* invoke even *GUI*-subsystem applications synchronously (unlike when launched from an *interactive* `cmd.exe` session).

  - By contrast, PowerShell launches GUI-subsystem applications *consistently asynchronously* (whether interactively or from a script file), unless additional actions are taken - see below.

---

<sup>A note on **`Start-Process`'s syntax**, given that the sample calls below do not show **how to pass *arguments*** to the target application: The best approach is to **pass them in a *single string***, e.g.

`Start-Process -Wait msiexec '/i some.msi'` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62784608/45375)</sup>

**To get predictable behavior in both the regular console and in the [obsolescent](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) ISE**:

- **To start a GUI application *asynchronously*** (return to the prompt right away / continue executing the script), **execute it directly**; e.g.:

  - `notepad.exe`

    - Invoking Notepad directly makes it run asynchronously, because it is a GUI-subsystem application.
  - If you still want **to *track* the process and later check whether it is still running and what its exit code was** on termination, use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) with the **`-PassThru`** switch , which returns a [`[System.Diagnostic.Process]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instance:

    - `$process = Start-Process -PassThru notepad.exe`

      - **`$process.HasExited`** later tells you whether the process is still running.

        - To **wait *synchronously*** for the process to terminate at some *later* point, use **`$process | Wait-Process`** or **`$process.WaitForExit()`**  (to wait *right away*, use `Start-Process`' `-Wait` switch - see below).

          - Both `Wait-Process` and `.WaitForExit()` optionally support a *timeout*. With `Wait-Process`, you can specify a `-Timeout` value in seconds; a non-terminating error is reported if the process doesn't terminate within the timeout period, causing `$?` to reflect `$False`.
      - Once the process has exited, **`$process.ExitCode` tells you the exit code** (which may not tell you much in the case of a GUI application).
- **To start a GUI application *synchronously*** (block until the application terminates), use **`Start-Process -Wait`**; e.g.:

  - `Start-Process -Wait notepad.exe`

    - **`-Wait`** tells [`Start-Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) to wait until the process created terminates; this is the equivalent of `start /wait notepad.exe` in a `cmd.exe` session / batch file.
    - **In the rare event that the GUI application reports a meaningful *exit code* (e.g, `msiexec`)** , you can obtain it as follows:

      - `$exitCode = (Start-Process -PassThru -Wait notepad.exe).ExitCode`
  - There's a **non-obvious alternative** to `Start-Process -Wait`:

    - **Pipe to `Write-Output`**: This takes advantage of the fact that using a command *in the non-final segment of a pipeline* forces its *synchronous* execution. That is, if you pipe the GUI-subsystem application call to another command, PowerShell will wait for its completion. While which specific command you pipe to isn't important, the most versatile choice is `Write-Output`, though **if you know that the GUI application produces no stdout output (GUI applications rarely do), you can also use `Out-Null`**:<sup>[1]</sup>; e.g.:

      - `notepad.exe | Write-Output`
    - This **approach has two advantages**:

      - If arguments must be passed to the GUI application, they can be passed directly, as usual - rather than indirectly, via `Start-Process`'s `-ArgumentList` parameter.
      - **In the (rare) event that a GUI application reports a meaningful process *exit code* (e.g, `msiexec.exe`)**, this approach (unlike `Start-Process -Wait`) causes it to be reflected in the **[automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode)**.
  - Yet **another alternative** is to **call via `cmd /c`**: `/c` causes `cmd.exe` to wait even for GUI-subsystem applications to exit (even though it doesn't do so from a `cmd.exe` command prompt); `$LASTEXITCODE` is also properly set in this case.

    - While slightly slower due to the extra process (`cmd.exe`), the advantage is that you get **more explicit control over the exact process command line in terms of *quoting***.
    - This can be helpful with applications that require nonstandard escaping of embedded `"` chars. or require *partial* double-quoting of arguments, such as `msiexec` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50868019/45375) for more information.
  - Note that ***none* of these approaches work for GUI applications that *delegate launching to a different, preexisting process and then exit***, which applies to applications such as:

    - Web browsers (e.g. Microsoft Edge, Chrome, Brave)
    - Some editors, such as Visual Studio Code
    - UWP applications such as Calculator (`calc.exe`)
    - In such cases, control is returned as soon as the originally launched process exits.

---

Note that for ***console*-subsystem applications** (e.g., `findstr.exe`), ***synchronous* execution is the default**; `Start-Process` is only needed for GUI applications (and for special situations, such as wanting to run an application in a *new console window* or with *elevation* (run as admin)).

To **run a console application or shell command *asynchronously*** (without opening a new console window), you have the following options:

- [*Preferred*] **Use [`Start-Job`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job) kick off the command, and [`Receive-Job`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job) to receive its output / success status later**.

  - `$j = Start-Job { sleep 2; 'hi' }`
  - To synchronously wait for this job to finish (and remove it automatically), use
    `Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob $j`
  - In **PowerShell (Core) 6+**:

    - You can use the **simpler `... &` syntax** (as in
      POSIX-like Unix shells such as `bash`) in lieu of `Start-Job`; e.g.:

      - `$j = & { sleep 2; 'hi!' } &`
    - Better yet, you can use the **lighter-weight, faster** **[`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob)** cmdlet, which uses *threads* for concurrency, but otherwise seamlessly integrates with the other `*-Job` cmdlets (note that it has no short-hand syntax):

      - `$j = Start-ThreadJob { sleep 2; 'hi' }`
- [*Not advisable*] You can use something like `Start-Process -NoNewWindow powershell -Args ...`, but it is ill-advised:

  - Passing a shell command to `powershell` via `Start-Process` requires intricate quoting based on obscure rules - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44986341/45375) of mine for background information.
  - Any stdout and stderr output produced by the application / shell command will by default arrive *asynchronously* in the current console, interspersed with what you're doing interactively.
  - While you can redirect these streams to *files* with `RedirectStandardOutput` and `-RedirectStandardError` (and stdin input via `-RedirectStandardInput`) and you can use `-PassThru` to obtain a process-information object to determine the status and exit code of the process, `Start-Job` and `Receive-Job` are a simpler, more convenient alternative.

---

P.S.: I don't have an explanation for why `cmd.exe "/c start notepad.exe"` is blocking in the ISE but not in the regular console. Given the solutions above, however, getting to the bottom of this discrepancy may not be needed.

---

<sup>[1] In *rare cases*, a GUI application may *explicitly attach* to the caller's console and write information to it; `Write-Output` surfaces this information. If you don't want to surface it, use `Out-Null`.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the info, although doesn't get down to the differences I saw. If we throw out the powershell ISE I was able to get them all the behave the same. After troubleshooting more I determined using `$process.WaitForExit()` on a new powershell process caused some weird deadlock if output was redirected. If I instead did a `Wait-Process -Id $process.Id` it behaved the same as the other scenarios.

Comment: @playsted: My point was that with the solutions above the differences become _moot_. If you still see differences: please provide a concrete example.

Comment: I don't have the ability to modify the powershell I'm running. They are build scripts written and maintained by other people. I just need to make sure they behave the same as if they were being run directly. Spawning in a new process is necessary under some circumstances (eg. if it needs to run under a different user account).

Comment: @playsted: As a general rule: unless there are performance problems, stick with PowerShell's cmdlets (as opposed to calling methods on .NET object).

Comment: @playsted: Understood. I've incorporated `Wait-Process` in the answer. As the answer stands now: is your scenario not covered in a way that works predictably in both the ISE and the regular console? Note that for simply _running_ prepackaged functionality, I'd advise against using the ISE, given that repeated invocations of a given script run in the _same session_, with previous invocations potentially causing side effects.

Comment: @playsted: As for running under a different user account: both `Start-Job` and `Start-Process` have a `-Credential` parameter; beware of issues relating to what the current directory is.

Comment: I was only using the ISE for experimentation and noticed it behaved differently as well. I was using the .Net `Process` object as I needed custom output redirection. AFIAK all the other methods only support redirecting to a file.

Comment: @playsted: Re not needing files as redirection targets: If you use `Start-Job` / `... &`, `Receive-Job` actually returns _objects_ to you, as you would receive if you ran the command directly (almost - serialization and deserialization are involved). However, as of PSv6-beta.4, there is a [known bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3130) with respect to capturing the _error-stream_ output (among others)

Answer (score 1):

Take out the start and it waits `cmd /c notepad`.  Otherwise `cmd /c start /wait notepad` waits.  cmd's start builtin runs in the background by default.