# The argument is null or empty: Start-Process error when invoking msiexec.exe for uninstallation

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, parameter-passing, start-process

```
Get-Process | ? {$_.ProcessName -eq "DellCommandUpdate"} | Stop-Process -Force

$Params = @(
    "/qn"
    "/norestart"
)

Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList $Params -Wait
```

I'm trying to uninstall Dell Command Update from a few laptops with older versions. I'm getting this error, below?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I tested your code and did not receive the error you're seeing. My first thought is because you're missing a comma: `$Params = @("/qn", "/norestart")`. But I tested without the comma and still no error. Also, I did receive a different error from msiexec, which is solved by Tanaka's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Msiexec.exe` [requires the path to the program you want to install or uninstall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msiexec).
You also need the `/x` flag to specify that it is an uninstall, otherwise you're going to run it as an install. Try this:

```
$MSIExec = "msiexec.exe"
$Params = @(
    "/qn",
    "/norestart",
    "/x",
    "<Path to package.msi>"
)
& "$MSIExec" $Params
```

I'm inclined to consider this a duplicate question to the more generic "How do I run executable files with arguments in Powershell" question which has a similar answere here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22247408/1618897

But, considering this is a new account, and you clearly showed what you've done, I think this is still valid.

EDIT: This answer runs asynchronously, see mklement0's answer for a 1:1 solution for a synchronous solution (which matches this question directly).

Comment: This is true but it would not result in the error they're seeing. Their error is thrown by a bad parameter on `Start-Process`, not by `msiexec`

Comment: That is true, which most likely means that this is run in ISE and that the $Params = @() section was not even run at all. Copy-pasting OP's code runs as is in my environment.

Answer (score 2):

- Your screenshot is not consistent with your code, because it implies that you passed (a variable containing) either `$null`, or an *empty array* (`@()`) to the `-ArgumentList` parameter of [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)
- Your code as shown would *technically* work - in the sense that `Start-Process` would succeed in *launching* [`msiexec.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/command-line-options), but - as [Tanaka Saito's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77985782/45375) notes - the arguments passed to `msiexec.exe`'s do not form a complete command, due to the absence of an `/x` (uninstallation) argument specifying the target `.msi` file.
- Adding this missing information to `$Parameters` would make your `Start-Process` call work:<sup>[1]</sup>

  ```bash
  $Params = @(
    '/qn'
    '/norestart'
    '/x'
    'someInstaller.msi' # specify the .msi file here
  )
  ```
- However, there is a **better way to invoke `msiexec.exe` from PowerShell**, namely in a way that:

  - is syntactically simpler, due to using direct invocation.
  - automatically reflects the installer's *exit code* in the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode) (with `Start-Process`, you'd have to add `-PassThru` in order to receive and capture a process-information object whose `.ExitCode` property you'd have to query).

    ```bash
     # Executes synchronously due to the `| Write-Output` trick,
     # reflects the exit code in $LASTEXITCODE.
     msiexec /qn /norestart /x someInstaller.msi | Write-Output
    ```
  - Note:

    - Piping to `Write-Output` is a simple way to ensure *synchronous* execution of *GUI*-subsystem applications such as `msiexec.exe`: involving the [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipelines) this way makes PowerShell wait for the application's termination and also reports its exit code.
    - There are cases where passing property values to `msiexec.exe` from PowerShell causes problems, namely when a value contains *spaces* and therefore requires *partial quoting* (e.g. `FOO="bar baz"`). In that case, you can use the following alternative, via `cmd.exe /c`:

      ```bash
       # Executes synchronously,
       # reflects the exit code in $LASTEXITCODE.
       # '...' encloses the entire msiexec command line
       # Use "..." if you need string interpolation, and `" for embedded "
       cmd /c 'msiexec /qn /norestart /x someInstaller.msi'
      ```

      - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50868019/45375) for details.
    - Finally, note that `Start-Process -Wait` - unlike direct invocation / invocation via `cmd.exe /c` - technically waits for the entire child process *tree* to terminate, which can cause apparent hangs if an installer happens to *asynchronously* launch a child process that is designed to outlive the installer process (`msiexec.exe`) itself - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78181214/45375) for an example.

---

<sup>[1] However, due to a [long-standing bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576), it is ultimately better to encode all arguments in a *single string*, because it makes the situational need for *embedded* double-quoting explicit - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76713933/45375).</sup>