# PowerShell Start-Process infinite execution of installer

Tags: powershell, inno-setup, synchronous, start-process

I have Inno Setup installer that run in very silent mode (it's working).

But when I'm running my Inno Setup installer through PowerShell script with admin rights – I get endless execution. Also, the following script code (`SetEnvironmentVariable`) is not executed even after successful installation.

```
$installerArguments = $requiredInstallerArguments + $additionalInstallerArguments

Start-Process -FilePath $installerFile.FullName -ArgumentList $installerArguments -Wait

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('WebPort', (GetValueByKey -array $additionalInstallerArguments -key "/webport"), [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

Why does this happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes I have to use the `.WaitForExit()` method

```
$Process = Start-Process -FilePath $installerFile.FullName -ArgumentList $installerArguments -PassThru
$Process.WaitForExit()
```

`Start-Process` ... `-Wait` behaves differently than `(Start-Process ... -PassThru).WaitForExit()` / `Start-Process` ... `-PassThru | Wait-Process`: the former waits for the entire child process tree to terminate, whereas the latter return once the immediate child process has terminated (see [GitHub issue #15555](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15555)). Thus, if an installer spawns a child process that keeps running after the installer has exited, `-Wait` won't return until that child process terminates.

In SysInternals Process Monitor, you can use Tools->Process Tree to see these process trees.

Answer (score 0):

To complement [Prodige69's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78182028/45375):

Another way to **wait *only* for `msiexec.exe`** (and child processes *synchronously* launched from it, if any) rather than its entire child process *tree* (`msiexec.exe` plus any child processes launched *asynchronously* from it, which is the cause of the problem here) is to use ***direct invocation* or invocation via `cmd.exe /c`**:

These are ***syntactically easier* alternatives** to using `(Start-Process ... -PassThru).WaitForExit()` or `Start-Process ... -PassThru | Wait-Process`, which also automatically reflect `msiexec`'s process exit code in the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode):

Note: I'm using `msiexec.exe` in the sample commands below, but the same applies analogously to any installer; in your case, with the direct invocation technique, substitute `& $installerFile.FullName` for `msiexec`, with the `cmd.exe /c` technique, substitute `"$($installerFile.FullName)"`

- Using **direct invocation**, via a trick to make the call *synchronous*:

```bash
# To build an argument list *programmatically*, create an *array*
$installerArguments = '/i', 'sample.msi', '/qn'

# Executes *synchronously*, due to `| Out-Null`
# Process exit code is reported in $LASTEXITCODE afterwards.
# Equivalent of: 
#   msiexec /i sample.msi /qn | Out-Null
msiexec $installerArguments | Out-Null
```

- Calling **via `cmd /c`**, which allows you to control quoting explicitly, which is required for property values that require *partial* quoting:

```bash
# Here, encode all arguments in a *single string*, using embedded double-quoting.
$installerArgumentList = '/i sample.msi /qn PROP="Value with spaces"'

# Executes *synchronously*, due to `cmd /c`
# Process exit code is reported in $LASTEXITCODE afterwards.
cmd /c "msiexec $installerArguments"
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50868019/45375) for background information.