# AzCopy not working through Start-Process in PS Script

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to figure out how to make AzCopy work with PS command "Start-Process" in PS script. I am trying to put together a PS script that downloads a folder named "Languages" from Azure Storage Blob Container to local disk using SAS token.

My script looks as following:

```
Start-Process `
    -FilePath "C:\temp\AzCopy\azcopy.exe" `
    -ArgumentList "cp 'https://<storageaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net/<blobcontainername>/Languages?<SASTOKEN>' 'C:\Temp' --recursive" `
    -Wait `
    -Passthru
```

this syntax gives me the following output:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName                                                                                                                         
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------                                                                                                                         
     19       3     1492       2004       0,00   2520   1 azcopy
```

which immediately exits and nothing happens.
If I run AzCopy manually as:

```
azcopy cp 'https://<storageaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net/<blobcontainername>/Languages?<SASTOKEN>' 'C:\Temp' --recursive
```

it works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is *no* good reason to use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) to invoke *console* applications - just invoke them *directly*, as in your second code snippet.

By default, `Start-Process` produces *no* output, and (on Windows) runs in a *new console window*.

With `-PassThru` it outputs a *process-information* object representing the launched process, i.e. an instance of [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process), and the output shown in your question is the *default output formatting* for such an instance.

Use of `Start-Process` does *not* allow returning the launched process' *output*; the only way to do that is to use the `-RedirectStandardOutput` and/or `-RedirectStandardError` parameters to redirect the process' native output streams to - invariably *text-only* - files.

By contrast, *direct* invocation maps the process' *stdout* stream to PowerShell's equivalent success [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) and, on demand, via a `2>` [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection), allows redirecting the *stderr* stream.

For guidance on when use of `Start-Process` is and isn't appropriate, see [this GitHub docs issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6239).

Comment: Excellent answer as usual of course! What about that wait [`-wait`] factor considering needing that to complete then when it is done, do something else non-`azcopy` but it depending on that to complete first? That's the only "maybe" good reason perhaps but I'm sure you know a way to handle that too!!

Comment: Thank you, @BitcoinMurderousManiac. _Console[-subsystem]_ applications on Windows invariably execute _synchronously_ (blocking) when you invoke them _directly_. Only _GUI[-subsystem]_ applications require use of either (a) `Start-Process -Wait` _or_ (b) a direct-invocation _workaround_ such as piping to `| Out-Null` or `| Write-Output` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45131324/45375).