# Powershell DISM and SFC Script with Transcript

Tags: powershell, transcription, dism, sfc

```
Write-Host "DISM and SFC" -ForegroundColor Cyan
Start-Transcript C:\DISM_SFC.txt
Start-Process -FilePath "dism.exe" -ArgumentList '/online /cleanup-image /analyzecomponentstore' -Wait -NoNewWindow
Start-Process -FilePath "dism.exe" -ArgumentList '/online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup' -Wait -NoNewWindow
Start-Process -FilePath "dism.exe" -ArgumentList '/online /cleanup-image /checkhealth' -Wait -NoNewWindow
Start-Process -FilePath "dism.exe" -ArgumentList '/online /cleanup-image /scanhealth' -Wait -NoNewWindow
Start-Process -FilePath "dism.exe" -ArgumentList '/online /cleanup-image /restorehealth' -Wait -NoNewWindow
Start-Process -FilePath "sfc.exe" -ArgumentList '/scannow' -Wait -NoNewWindow
Stop-Transcript
Write-Host "DISM and SFC completed"`n -ForegroundColor Magenta
```

I'm trying to add Start-Transcript/Stop-Transcript to my tune-up script and I can't get it to work properly. It performs the commands, creates the text file, but doesn't add the results in the text file.

I think the issue is related to the -NoNewWindow but I'm kind of lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dism.exe` and `sfc.exe` are *console-subsystem* Windows applications.

To invoke them synchronously, with their output streams (stdout, stderr) connected to PowerShell's [output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) , invoke them *directly*; e.g.:

```bash
dism.exe/online /cleanup-image /analyzecomponentstore
# ...
sfc.exe /scannow
```

Note:

- If your executable name or path were *quoted* or expressed via *variable references*, you'd need to prepend `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) (e.g., `$exe = 'dism.exe'; & $exe ...`)

This is the prerequisite for output to show up in your transcripts.

By contrast, if you use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process)'s `-NoNewWindow` switch, the program's output prints *directly to the console*, with no ability to capture it in PowerShell.

An additional advantage of direct, synchronous execution is that the executable's *process exit code* will be reflected in the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode)

---

For regular invocations without special requirements - such as wanting to run in a new window, with elevation, or as a different user - `Start-Process` is usually the wrong tool.

While you can use it to make a call to a *GUI*(-subsystem) application synchronous (such applications run *asynchronously* by default), namely with `-Wait`, a trick allows you to use direct invocation there as well: Pipe to `Out-Null` (or, in the rare event that your GUI application explicitly attaches to the caller's console and produces output, to `Write-Output`); e.g.:

```bash
# Opens Notepad and waits until it's closed.
Notepad.exe | Out-Null
```

- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45131324/45375) for more information about this technique.

[GitHub docs issue #6239](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6239) provides guidance on when use of `Start-Process` is and isn't appropriate.

Comment: That worked. The reason why I didn't invoke it directly was that on some computers, it would open the command in a new PowerShell window. I'm not sure why sometimes it would work perfectly, and other times it would open a separate window...

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Moxadonis. That the commands would sometimes run in a new window is mysterious.