# How to run base64 code in powershell with ascii?

Tags: windows, powershell, base64, ascii

I would like to run command `mkdir C:\Temp\555` in Powershell via a Base64-encoded *string*.

This code should work

```
$4 = "bWtkaXIgQzpcVGVtcFw1NTU="

$code = [Text.Encoding]::Utf8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String($4))

powershell $code
```

but if i convert `$code` to ASCII, how can I run it like that, because this one won't work:

```
$4 = "bWtkaXIgQzpcVGVtcFw1NTU="

$code = [char]091+[char]084+[char]101+[char]120+[char]116+[char]046+[char]069+[char]110+[char]099+[char]111+[char]100+[char]105+[char]110+[char]103+[char]093+[char]058+[char]058+[char]085+[char]116+[char]102+[char]056+[char]046+[char]071+[char]101+[char]116+[char]083+[char]116+[char]114+[char]105+[char]110+[char]103+[char]040+[char]091+[char]067+[char]111+[char]110+[char]118+[char]101+[char]114+[char]116+[char]093+[char]058+[char]058+[char]070+[char]114+[char]111+[char]109+[char]066+[char]097+[char]115+[char]101+[char]054+[char]052+[char]083+[char]116+[char]114+[char]105+[char]110+[char]103+[char]040+[char]036+[char]052+[char]041+[char]041

powershell $code
```

because the last code doesn't work while the first one does, any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string can be executed as a script through the CommandInvocationIntrinsics class method `InvokeScript`.

```
powershell $executioncontext.InvokeCommand.InvokeScript($code)
```

See [InvokeScript Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.commandinvocationintrinsics.invokescript?view=pscore-6.2.0) for more information.

Comment: `$executioncontext.InvokeCommand.InvokeScript($code)` is a more obscure way of calling `Invoke-Expression $code` (strictly speaking, `& { Invoke-Expression $code }`, but that the child scope makes no difference here) except that errors aren't surfaced. 
It is worth noting that a much more sensible way to pass the Base64-encoded `mkdir` command is to _directly_ pass it to `powershell -EncodedCommand`; however, for that to work the Base64 encoding would have to be based on UTF16-LE, not on UTF-8.

Answer (score 4):

Note: This answer addresses common use cases first; for a discussion of what you tried, see the bottom section.

---

Note: **If you just want to execute commands stored in a *string* from *inside* a PowerShell session**, *without needing to run commands in a child process*, use `Invoke-Expression`, but do note that [`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375):

<sup>Note: For illustrative purposes, I'm substituting command `Get-Date -UFormat "%s"` for your original command, `mkdir "C:\Temp\555"`. This `Get-Date` command prints the current point in time as a Unix timestamp, i.e., an integer denoting the seconds since 1 Jan 1970, midnight UTC; e.g., `1565229614` for `Wednesday, August 7, 2019 10:00:13 PM ETD`.</sup>

```sh
$cmd = 'Get-Date -UFormat "%s"'
Invoke-Expression $cmd  # Execute the string $cmd as code.
```

If you control construction of the commands, it's **better to store pieces of code as *script blocks* (`{ ... }`)** inside a PowerShell session:

```sh
$cmd = { Get-Date -UFormat "%s" }  # create a script block
& $cmd                             # execute the script block
```

---

#### How to pass a *complex command* to a PowerShell *child process* via its [*CLI*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), using the `-EncodedCommand` parameter:

---

- **From *outside* PowerShell**, use the **`-EncodedCommand` parameter**, which requires **a Base64 encoding of the bytes of a *UTF-16LE*-encoded string** ("Unicode"-encoded), not of a *UTF-8*-encoded one:

```sh
# Get the Base64-encoding of the bytes that make up the UTF-16LE
# ("Unicode") encoding of string 'Get-Date -UFormat "%s"'
# Assigns the following to $base64Cmd: 
#   'RwBlAHQALQBEAGEAdABlACAALQBVAEYAbwByAG0AYQB0ACAAIgAlAHMAIgA='
$base64Cmd = 
  [System.Convert]::ToBase64String(
     [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes(
       'Get-Date -UFormat "%s"'
     )
  )

powershell -EncodedCommand $base64Cmd  # executes: Get-Date -UFormat "%s"
```

<sup>Note: The above assumes *Windows PowerShell*. If you're using PowerShell *Core*, use `pwsh` instead of `powershell`.

Specifying the `System.` component in PowerShell type literals explicitly is optional; e.g., `[System.Text.Encoding]` can be shortened to `[Text.Encoding]`.</sup>

---

- **From *inside* PowerShell**, there's ***no* need to pass a Base64-encoded string** via 
  `-EncodedCommand` *explicitly*, because PowerShell does that *implicitly* when you **simply pass the code to execute *as a script block***(`{ ... }`):

```sh
powershell { Get-Date -UFormat "%s" }   # -command (-c) parameter implied
```

Note:

- You cannot refer to the *caller's* variables in a script block, but you can pass arguments to it via the `-args` parameter; e.g.:
  `powershell { Get-Date -UFormat $args[0] } -args '%s'`.

*Behind the scenes*, the appropriate Base64 encoding is performed, and the encoded command is passed to `-EncodedCommand`, as follows:

```sh
# The command to execute:
$cmd = 'Get-Date -UFormat "%s"'

# Obtain a Base64-encoded version of the command from the bytes of its
# UTF-16LE encoding.
$base64Cmd = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($cmd))

# Pass the result to the -EncodedCommand parameter:
powershell -EncodedCommand $base64Cmd -inputFormat xml -outputFormat xml
```

Note:

- `-inputFormat xml -outputFormat xml` are *automatically* added when you pass a *script block* to the (possibly positionally implied) `-Command` / `-c` parameter.
- They trigger CLIXML serializing of the arguments passed to as well as the output from the CLI call.
- This serialization is the same as the one used by PowerShell's [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote)  / background-job infrastructure and has two **benefits**:

  - **PowerShell's [output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) are preserved** (whereas passing a *string* `-Command` merges all output into the single standard stdout stream).
  - **Arguments and output are passed and received as *objects*** (rather than as *text only*, as happens when you pass a *string* `-Command`), albeit with the same limitations on type fidelity as in remoting - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375) for more information.
- The equivalent of using `-args` to **pass arguments** to a script block is to pass an explicitly Base64-encoded argument list to **`-encodedArguments` (`-ea`)**:

  - This parameter - undocumented as of this writing - additionally requires *serializing* the argument list to XML (CLIXML format) before Base64-encoding the result, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44986341/45375).

---

As for **what you tried**:

- Your 1st command works, because you're passing a decoded plain-text version of the `mkdir` command to `powershell.exe`, which implicitly binds to the `-Command` parameter and is executed as a command in the new PowerShell session.
  As an aside: `pwsh`, PowerShell *Core*'s CLI, now defaults to `-File`, so `-Command` (or `-c`) would have to be used explicitly.
- Your 2nd command does *not* work, because `$code` now contains the *plain text* of the *Base64-decoding command from your 1st command*.
  That command references variable `$4`, which the *new* PowerShell instance you're creating knows nothing about.

However, instead of trying to defer the decoding of the Base64-encoded `mkdir` command to the *new* PowerShell session, it makes much more sense to pass the Base64-encoded command *directly* to the new session (if a new session is even needed, see above), via `-EncodedCommand`.

However, `-EncodedCommand` requires a Base64 encoding based on UTF-16LE, not UTF-8 - see above for how to produce such an encoding explicitly (if needed).

If you're *given* a UTF-8-based Base64 encoding, you can translate it into a UTF-16LE-based one as follows:

```sh
# UTF-8-based Base64-encoding
$4 = "bWtkaXIgQzpcVGVtcFw1NTU="

# Decode to plain text.
$plainTextCode = [Text.Encoding]::Utf8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String($4))

# Re-encode to Base64 via UTF-16 ("Unicode"):
$utf16Base64Command = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($plainTextCode))

# Pass to powershell.exe via -EncodedCommand
powershell -EncodedCommand $code
```