# Secure String Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am getting an issue when trying to pass a `securestring` in to a powershell script, but it's coming back with this error?

> Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Password'.
> Cannot convert the "ConvertTo-SecureString" value
> of type "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString".

```
$SecureServiceAccountPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString  "somethingstong!" `
    -AsPlainText -Force   
$AgentAccount = "myAccount"
$ServiceAccountOU = "MYOU"
POWERSHELL -COMMAND $ADAccountScript `
    -ServiceAccountOU $ServiceAccountOU `
    -Account $AgentAccount `
    -Password $SecureAgentAccountPassword
```

The script that it's calling is this.

```
param(
 ##MasterKey for KeePass currently stored in a DB.  
  [Parameter(Position=0,mandatory=$true)] [string] $ServiceAccountOU,
 ##Account to be created in AD
  [Parameter(Position=1,mandatory=$true)] [string] $Account,

  [Parameter(Position=2,mandatory=$true)] [SecureString] $Password
 )

NEW-ADUSER -Name $Account `
    -AccountPassword $Password `
    -Path $SrviceAccountOU `
    -Enabled $True `
    -PasswordNeverExpires $True `
    -CannotChangePassword $True
```

Comment: Error states you are passing string,instead of secure string,do this


   `NEW-ADUSER -Name $Account -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)$Password`

Comment: but this is what is getting passed in?

Comment: $SecureServiceAccountPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString  "somethingstong!" -AsPlainText -Force

Answer (score 3):

**To pass a `[securestring]` ([`System.Security.SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Security.SecureString)) instance *as such* via PowerShell's CLI** ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) in Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh) in PowerShell (Core) 7+), **you must pass the command to execute (`-Command` / `-c`) *as a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks)***.<sup>[1]</sup>

- Note: While use of `[securestring]` - assuming the input string wasn't obtained via a *plain-text* representation (as shown in the question) - is undoubtedly better than using plain-text passwords, **use of `[securestring]` in new projects is *discouraged***, because it offers *no* protection on *Unix*-like platforms and only *limited* protection on Windows. See [this .NET platform-compatibility recommendation](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60406968/45375).

Note that this **passing a *script block*** as the command to execute **only works when you call *from an existing PowerShell session*** - where the need to invoke a script *via another PowerShell instance* (the child process created by the CLI call) rather than by *direct invocation* (in-process in the same session) is unusual, however.

In your case, the simplest solution is:

```
powershell -c { 
  $scriptFile, $passThruArgs = $args
  & $scriptFile @passThruArgs
} -args $ADAccountScript, $ServiceAccountOU, $AgentAccount, $SecureServiceAccountPassword
```

Note that this relies on *positional* argument-passing.

If you wanted to use *named* arguments, as in your own attempt, you'd have to resort to hashtable-based [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting)

```
# Create the hashtable whose entries map onto the target
# script's parameters.
$htArgs = @{
    ServiceAccountOU = 'foo'
    Account          = 'bar'
    Password         = ConvertTo-SecureString  "somethingstrong!" -AsPlainText -Force
}

powershell -c { 
  $scriptFile, $passThruArgs = $args
  & $scriptFile @passThruArgs
} -args $ADAccountScript, $htArgs
```

---

<sup>[1] If you pass the `-Command` / `-c` argument *as a string* - which is the only option when calling PowerShell's CLI from *outside* PowerShell - a `[securestring]` is passed *as its string representation*, which is its *full type name, verbatim*: `'System.Security.SecureString'`; that is, the actual, "secure" content is *lost*.

By contrast, passing a *script block* triggers CLIXML-based serialization behind the scenes, where passing and receiving *objects* rather than *only text* is supported - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57404296/45375) for more information.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Your password is not passing to PS as secure string. So, you have to convert the same and pass it.

Replace this:

```
NEW-ADUSER -Name $Account -AccountPassword $Password -Path $SrviceAccountOU -Enabled $True -PasswordNeverExpires $True -CannotChangePassword $True
```

TO:

```
NEW-ADUSER -Name $Account -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "$password" -AsPlainText -Force) -Path $SrviceAccountOU -Enabled $True -PasswordNeverExpires $True -CannotChangePassword $True
```

Best way is to directly pass the credentials:

```
$User = "MyUserName"
$File = "C:\Temp 2\Password.txt"
$password = Get-Content "C:\Passwords\password.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString 
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("Luke",$password)
$MyCredential=New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, (Get-Content $File | ConvertTo-SecureString)

New-ADUser -credential $MyCredential # Followed by whatever you need except the username and password.
```