# powershell string urldecoding execution time

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cgi

Performing URLdecoding in CGI hybrid script by powershell oneliner:

```
echo %C4%9B%C5%A1%C4%8D%C5%99%C5%BE%C3%BD%C3%A1%C3%AD%C3%A9%C5%AF%C3%BA| powershell.exe "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web;[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode($Input) | Write-Host"
```

execution time of this oneliner is between 2-3 seconds on virtual machine. Is it because of .NET object is employed? Is there any way to decrease execution time? Have also some C written, lightning fast urldecode.exe utility, but unfortunatelly it does not eat STDIN.

Comment: I think you need to escape some of those `%` symbols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A note if you're passing the input data as a string *literal*, as in the sample call in the question (rather than as *output from a command*):

- If you're calling from an *interactive* `cmd.exe` session, `%C4%9B%C5%A1%C4%8D%C5%99%C5%BE%C3%BD%C3%A1%C3%AD%C3%A9%C5%AF%C3%BA` works as-is - unless any of the tokens between paired `%` instances happen to be the name of an existing environment variable (which seems unlikely).
- From a *batch* file, you'll have to *escape* the `%` chars. by *doubling* them - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31420292/45375); which you can obtain by applying the following PowerShell operation on the original string:

  ```
  '%C4%9B%C5%A1%C4%8D%C5%99%C5%BE%C3%BD%C3%A1%C3%AD%C3%A9%C5%AF%C3%BA' -replace '%', '%%'
  ```

---

> Is it because of .NET object is employed?

- Yes, `powershell.exe`, as a *.NET-based application* requires starting the latter's runtime (CLR), which is nontrivial in terms of performance.
- Additionally, `powershell.exe` *by default* loads the initialization files listed in its `$PROFILE` variable, which can take additional time.

  - Pass the `-NoProfile` CLI option to suppress that.

---

> Have also some C written, lightning fast `urldecode.exe` utility, but unfortunately it does not eat STDIN.

If so, pass the data *as an argument*, if feasible; e.g.:

```
urldecode.exe "%C4%9B%C5%A1%C4%8D%C5%99%C5%BE%C3%BD%C3%A1%C3%AD%C3%A9%C5%AF%C3%BA"
```

If the data comes from another command's output, you can use `for /f`  to capture in a variable first, and then pass the latter.

---

If you do need to call `powershell.exe`, PowerShell's [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), after all:

There's not *much* you can do in terms of optimizing performance:

- Add `-NoProfile`, as suggested.
- Pass the input data *as an argument*.
- Avoid unnecessary calls such as [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) and rely on PowerShell's *implicit output behavior* instead.<sup>[1]</sup>

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile -c "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web;[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode('%C4%9B%C5%A1%C4%8D%C5%99%C5%BE%C3%BD%C3%A1%C3%AD%C3%A9%C5%AF%C3%BA')"
```

---

#### [1] Optional reading: How do I output *machine-parseable data* from a PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) call?

Note: The sample commands are assumed to be run from `cmd.exe` / outside PowerShell.

- PowerShell's CLI only supports *text* as output, not also raw byte data.
- In order to output *data* for later *programmatic processing*, you may have to explicitly ensure that what is output is *machine-parseable* rather than something that is meant for *display only*.

There are **two basic choices**:

- **Rely on PowerShell's default output formatting** for outputting what are ***strings*** (text) to begin with, as well as for ***numbers*** - though for fractional and very large or small non-integer numbers additional effort may be required.
- **Explicitly use a *structured, text-based data format***, such as CSV or Json, to represent ***complex objects***.

---

**Rely on PowerShell's default output formatting:**

- If the output data is *itself* text (strings), no extra effort is needed. This applies to your case, and therefore simply *implicitly* outputting the string returned from the `[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode()` call is sufficient:

  ```
  # A simple example that outputs a 512-character string; note that 
  # printing to the _console_ (terminal) will insert line breaks for 
  # *display*, but the string data itself does _not_ contain any 
  # (other than a single _trailing one), irrespective of the 
  # console window width:
  powershell -noprofile -c "'x' * 512"
  ```
- If the output data comprises *numbers*, you may have to apply *explicit, culture-invariant formatting* if your code must run with different cultures in effect:

  - True *integer* types do *not* require special handling, as their string representation is in effect culture-neutral.
  - However, *fractional* numbers (`[double]`, `[decimal]`) do use the *current culture's* decimal mark, which later processing may not expect:

    ```
    # With, say, culture fr-FR (French) in effect, this outputs
    # "1,2", i.e. uses a *comma* as the decimal mark.
    powershell -noprofile -c "1.2"

    # Simple workaround: Let PowerShell *stringify* the number explicitly
    # in an *expandable* (interpolating) string, which uses
    # the *invariant culture* for formatting, where the decimal
    # mark is *always "." (dot).
    # The following outputs "1.2", irrespective of what culture is in effect.    
    powershell -noprofile -c " $num=1.2; \"$num\" "
    ```
  - Finally, very large and very small `[double]` values can result in *exponential* notation being output (e.g., `5.1E-07` for `0.00000051`); to avoid that, [explicit number formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) is required, which can be done via the `.ToString()` method:

    ```
    # The following outputs 0.000051" in all cultures, as intended.
    powershell -noprofile -c "$n=0.000051; $n.ToString('F6', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)"
    ```
- **More work is needed if you want to output representations of *complex objects* in machine-parseable form**, as discussed in the **next section**.

  - Relying on PowerShell's default output formatting is *not* an option in this case, because implicit output and (equivalent explicit [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) calls) cause the CLI to apply *for-display-only* formatting, which is meaningful to the *human observer* but cannot be robustly *parsed*.

    ```
    # Produces output helpful to the *human observer*, but isn't
    # designed for *parsing*.
    # `Get-ChildItem` outputs [System.IO.FileSystemInfo] objects.
    powershell -noprofile -c "Get-ChildItem /"
    ```
  - Note that use of **[`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) is *not* an alternative**: `Write-Host` fundamentally isn't designed for *data* output, and the textual representation it creates for complex objects are typically not even meaningful to the *human* observer - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58240860/45375) for more information.

---

**Use a *structured, text-based data format*, such as CSV or Json:**

Note:

- Hypothetically, the simplest approach is to use the CLI's `-OutputFormat Xml` option, which serializes the output using the XML-based CLIXML format PowerShell itself uses for remoting and background jobs - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375).
- However, this format is only natively understood by PowerShell itself, and for third-party applications to parse it they'd have to be .NET-based and use the [PowerShell SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation).

  - Also, this format is *automatically* used for both serialization and deserialization if you call another PowerShell instance *from PowerShell*, with the command specified *as a script block* (`{ ... }`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57404296/45375). However, there is rarely a need to call the PowerShell CLI from PowerShell itself, and direct invocation of PowerShell code and scripts provides full type fidelity as well as better performance.
- Finally, note that *all* serialization formats, including CSV and JSON discussed below, have limits with respect to faithfully representing all aspects of the data, though `-OutputFormat Xml` comes closest.

PowerShell comes with cmdlets such as **[`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv)** and **[`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json)**, which make it easy to convert output to the structured CSV and JSON formats.

Using a [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item) call to get information about PowerShell's installation directory (`$PSHOME`) as an example; `Get-Item` outputs a [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) instance in this case:

- Use of [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv):

```
C:\>powershell -noprofile -c "Get-Item $PSHOME | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation"
"PSPath","PSParentPath","PSChildName","PSDrive","PSProvider","PSIsContainer","Mode","BaseName","Target","LinkType","Name","FullName","Parent","Exists","Root","Extension","CreationTime","CreationTimeUtc","LastAccessTime","LastAccessTimeUtc","LastWriteTime","LastWriteTimeUtc","Attributes"
"Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell","v1.0","C","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem","True","d-----","v1.0","System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]",,"v1.0","C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0","WindowsPowerShell","True","C:\",".0","12/7/2019 4:14:52 AM","12/7/2019 9:14:52 AM","3/14/2021 10:33:10 AM","3/14/2021 2:33:10 PM","11/6/2020 3:52:41 AM","11/6/2020 8:52:41 AM","Directory"
```

<sup>Note: `-NoTypeInformation` is no longer needed in PowerShell (Core) 7+</sup>

- Using [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json):

```
C:\>powershell -noprofile -c "Get-Item $PSHOME | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 1"
{
    "Name":  "v1.0",
    "FullName":  "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0",
    "Parent":  {
                   "Name":  "WindowsPowerShell",
                   "FullName":  "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell",
                   "Parent":  "System32",
                   "Exists":  true,
                   "Root":  "C:\\",
                   "Extension":  "",
                   "CreationTime":  "\/Date(1575710092565)\/",
                   "CreationTimeUtc":  "\/Date(1575710092565)\/",
                   "LastAccessTime":  "\/Date(1615733476841)\/",
                   "LastAccessTimeUtc":  "\/Date(1615733476841)\/",
                   "LastWriteTime":  "\/Date(1575710092565)\/",
                   "LastWriteTimeUtc":  "\/Date(1575710092565)\/",
                   "Attributes":  16
               },
    "Exists":  true
    // ...
}
```

Since JSON is a hierarchical data format, the serialization depth must be limited with `-Depth` in order to prevent "runaway" serialization when serializing arbitrary .NET types; this isn't necessary for `[pscustomobject]` and `[hashtable]` object graphs composed of primitive .NET types only.

Comment: Web server pass POST received data to the STDIN of cmd script, so no need percent doubling in this case. `-NoProfile` cut execution time by half to 1.2 secs is far enough for me, thanks. `Write-Host` usage is TRUE necessary in PS oneliners, otherwise PS console cut STDOUT https://ss64.com/ps/write-host.html

Comment: @user2956477, understood re stdin; I've updated the answer to make it clearer that escaping is only needed for _literals_. Glad to hear that `-NoProfile` helped. `Write-Host` is actually _not_ needed with _string_ output, and is in general always the wrong tool for outputting _data_ - please see the bottom section I've added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your addendum, hopefully I understan it even partialy. Unsing many PS various oneliners in my batch script, so should I replace all trailing Write-Host with Write-Output? Does this reliable avoid unwanted 'console width -1' linewraps?

Comment: @user2956477, you don't need explicit `Write-Output` calls: any result that isn't captured in a variable, sent to another command in a (PowerShell command-internal) pipeline or redirected to a file is _implicitly_ output, as shown in the answer. If you have a console width problem, the implication is that you're mistakenly outputting _for-display-only_ representations of _complex objects_, and in that case you need to resort to explicit use of structured data formats instead - or explicitly choose to output just _one property_ of such objects that is itself either a string or a number.

Comment: Thanks a lot (no irony) you tried to teach me internal PS "output producing" issues. I do not know PS at all, my only 'language' are batch scripts (I am not a programmer). Utilizing PS oneliners founded on internet for tasks out of batch scripts ability. I am not able to discovery which oneliner produce what type of output. I need practical way to ensure the textual output will not be distorted, and Write-Host give me this. Maybe this is not correct way, but it enough and I have no good reason to change it.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @user2956477. I understand the pragmatic perspective, but to give you two hints: (a) your command should work _without_ `Write-Host` and (b) here's an example of where `Write-Host` is unhelpful: `powershell -NoProfile -c "@{ foo = 1; bar = 2 } | Write-Host"`. To put it differently: you need to understand _what types of objects_ the PowerShell CLI call outputs and plan accordingly.