# forward function to new powershell session or use Invoke-command?

Tags: function, powershell, invoke-command

I have below command, that I want to be called from my script, how can I pass the function `New-PopupMessage` ?

```
Start-Process $PSScriptRoot\ServiceUI.exe 
-process:TSProgressUI.exe %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe 
-noprofile -windowstyle hidden -executionpolicy bypass  -command New-PopupMessage @Params
```

I also tried with a `Invoke-command`

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
Start-Process $PSScriptRoot\ServiceUI.exe 
-process:TSProgressUI.exe %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe 
-noprofile -windowstyle hidden -executionpolicy bypass 
-command ${function:New-PopupMessage} -ArgumentList @Params
 }
```

Comment: The code you posted is broken. Please do not wrap code in arbitrary places.

Comment: Can you use a script instead of a function?  This comes up in jobs and foreach -parallel too.

Comment: Well I have it working by calling a script with ServiceUI.exe, but I want to reuse the code therefor a function, ServiceUI needed in order to run the script in user context

Comment: Patricks Solution is working for me, I will try to combine it with @mklement0 link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local functions are only known in that [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-6). A function defined in a script is therefore not known when you open a new powershell process. You could create a [module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-script-module?view=powershell-6) so your function will be available for other scripts / powershell sessions. Or maybe this 'hack' will work for you. This example will pass the local function to a new powershell session. This solution will only work for "simple" functions. See also the comment from mklement0. He recommends the following link: [Run PowerShell custom function in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44981177/run-powershell-custom-function-in-new-window/44986341#44986341)

```
function New-PopupMessage
{
    param
    (
        [System.String]$P1,
        [System.String]$P2
    )

    Out-Host -InputObject ('Output: ' + $P1 + ' ' + $P2)
}

New-PopupMessage -P1 'P1' -P2 'P2'


$Function = Get-Command -Name New-PopupMessage -CommandType Function

Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList '-noexit', "-command &{function $($Function.Name) {$($Function.ScriptBlock)}; $($Function.Name) -P1 'P1' -P2 'P2'}"
```

Comment: Nicely done, but while your specific function definition works, the solution isn't _robust_, because `"` chars. in the function definition break it, as may `\ ` instances. Unfortunately, the solution isn't as simple as applying `-replace '["\\]', '\$&'` first, as I initially thought, because it wouldn't work properly with a function such as  `function New-PopupMessage { "arguments: \$args\"; gi c:\ }`, for instance. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44986341/45375