# Powershell: Call function during Start-Process

Tags: powershell

I have a function called RemoveSoftware:

```
function RemoveSoftware {
        foreach ($utility in $toRemove) {                    
            Try {
                winget uninstall -e $utility
                $wingetResult.Add("$node`n")
                Start-Sleep -s 6
                Wait-Process winget -Timeout 90 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue              
            }        
            Catch {
                Write-Host "Paket $utility konnte nicht deinstalliert werden. " -ForegroundColor red                 
            }      
        }
    }
```

This function is in a ps1 file. In the same file I want to start another powershell window which should start this function.

I tried this here:

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "-command Start-Transcript C:\temp\winget-start.log -Append; & {$RemoveSoftware} | Out-Host" -WindowStyle Normal
```

But this don't work.
Also I tried several other things like Invoke-Expression and so on. Neither of it worked:(
Has someone a tipp for solving this problem?

Comment: First ask yourself: how would you call this function in general (leaving the `Start-Process` and `PowerShell.exe` process shells out of it)? And how do you provide the `$toRemove` list to the function?

Comment: Hi, i would call it with only RemoveSoftware
$toRemove is an array with software names.

Comment: Ok, check what you just stated is correct by manually opening a new (elevated) PowerShell window and "*call it with only `RemoveSoftware $toRemove`*", or "*"*call it with only `RemoveSoftware <your utility>`*"... In other words, how is `$toRemove` populated? (Again, not even speaking about the `Start-Process` and `PowerShell.exe` process shells you want to use.) I suspect you missing a function [parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/09-functions#parameters) here...

Comment: Did you check the log file C:\temp\winget-start.log?  I log file doesn't exist you do not have permission to create log file or there is no temp folder.  You may need to run as admin.  So start PS by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44981177